# Рисование цветной карты категорий землепользования на Python?

Tags: python, numpy, графика, matplotlib

столкнулся со следующей задачей: нужно нарисовать цветную карту категорий землепользования по данным [Текст](http://d.zaix.ru/kvCJ.txt) (где каждый столбец это определенная категория), то есть что-то вроде рисунка:[image: Текст]

где синий цвет – вода, светло-коричневый – кустарник, черный – пашня, светло-зеленый – лиственный лес, серо-коричневый – смешанный лес, темно-зеленый – хвойный лес, красный – городская застройка. Как это можно осуществить на Python?
Раньше строил только цветные карты по одному набору данных ,например, по данным температуры воздуха (+поля ветров):
[image: Текст]

с помощью следующего кода:

```
#colormaps with wind's vectors (u,v) for xy_plane
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import numpy as np

#parameter name
def parName(file_list,i):
    with open(file_list[0]) as file:
        par_name = np.loadtxt(file, dtype='str', usecols=i)[1]
    file.close()
    return par_name

#read coordinates x,y and u,v components
def read_coord(file_list,cols):
    with open(file_list[0]) as file:
         coord = np.loadtxt(file,skiprows=2,usecols=cols)

В данном же случае, нужно сразу несколько наборов данных нарисовать. 
    file.close()
    x = coord[:,0].reshape(50,50)
    y = coord[:,1].reshape(50,50)
    return x, y

#determination of the borders of the color scale
def scale_bounds(file_list,i):
    with open(file_list[0]) as file:
        z = np.loadtxt(file,skiprows=2,usecols=i)
    file.close()
    minv = min(z)
    maxv = max(z)

    for f in file_list[1:]:
        with open(f) as file:
            z = np.loadtxt(file,skiprows=2,usecols=i)
        file.close()
        if minv>min(z):
            minv=min(z)
        if maxv<max(z):
            maxv = max(z)
    return minv, maxv

def draw_picture(file_list,i,x,y,u,v,scale_name,title,savepath):
    for f in file_list:
        with open(f) as file:
            data = np.loadtxt(file,skiprows=2,usecols=i).reshape(50, 50)
        file.close()
        levels = MaxNLocator(nbins='auto').tick_values(minv, maxv)
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
        ax = plt.subplot()
        cs = ax.contourf(x, y, data, levels=levels, cmap='jet')
        cbar = fig.colorbar(cs,label = scale_name)
        plt.title(title)
        ax.set_xlabel(parName(file_list,0))
        ax.set_ylabel(parName(file_list,1))
        q = ax.quiver(x, y, u, v)
        fig.savefig(savepath+parName(file_list,i)+'_'+f[-6:]+'.png')
        #plt.show()
    return 0

file_list = glob.glob('.../xy-plane/*.dat')
savepath = '.../xy_plane/'

#T10
i = 5
title = 'Temperature at a height of 10 meters from the surface'
scale_name1 = 'Temperature, C'
#par_name = parName(file_list,i)
cols=[0,1]
x, y = read_coord(file_list,cols)
cols=[2,3]
u, v = read_coord(file_list,cols)
minv, maxv = scale_bounds(file_list,i)
print('minvT=',minv,'maxvT=', maxv)
draw_picture(file_list,i,x,y,u,v,scale_name1,title,savepath)
```

Сейчас же нужно отрисовать сразу несколько массивов данных.

Comment: так а что вам мешает отрисовать все столбцы данных на одном холсте?

Comment: Я не знаю, как можно это осуществить. Может подскажите?

Comment: вы можете привести небольшой, но достаточный пример исходных данных и пример желаемого результата? ваш текстовый файл не позволяет понять, что за данные в нём.

Comment: Желаемый результат - представлен на первой картинке. В исходных данных первые два столбца это координаты по осям x, y. Что означают остальные данные, не столь важно. Главное мне разобраться, как отрисовать несколько наборов данных на одном холсте, а уже потом я сам распределю данные, как требуется. Если можно, можете, пожалуйста, привести пример кода на Python, как это реализуется?

Comment: Для того, чтобы привести пример кода на python применительно к вашим данным, надо понимать, какие данные из какого столбца берутся, помимо координат.

Comment: Для примера, можно взять первые 4 столбца после двух столбцов с координатами и отрисовать их разными цветами на одном холсте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, я не совсем понимаю, как у вас распределяются данные в исходном файле, но могу предложить такое решение:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm


df = pd.read_csv("kvCJ.csv", sep=r"\s+", header=None, usecols = [0, 1,3,4,5,6], names=["x", "y", "a", "b", "c", "d"])

df['a'].to_numpy().nonzero()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
categories = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
colors = iter(["yellow", "brown", "gray", "green"])

plt.scatter(df['x'], df['y'], color="lightblue", marker="s", s=50)

for ctg in categories:
    plt.scatter(df.loc[df[ctg].gt(0), 'x'], df.loc[df[ctg].gt(0), 'y'], color=next(colors), marker="s", s=50)


plt.show()
```

получим такой шедевр:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, Вам большое! А можно как-то пустоты по периметру убрать?

Comment: попробуйте перед `plt.show()` добавить команду `plt.autoscale(tight=True)`